# Resuming IntentService from Activity

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice

I have an `IntentService` in my background that already started and running.
Now I want to resuming this service from my activity, Any ideas?

Comment: you can see intent service lifecycle if that possible to resume i dont think so

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn Already saw, but did not find anything!

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean? An `IntentService` is, by design, not intended to keep "running". It is run on a single Thread for as long as the Intent handling takes. After that, it is not exactly _running_, more _waiting_. So what would _resume_ mean in this context?

Comment: @ClassStacker So if I want to keep running my `IntentService` what should I do? Should I change it to `Service` or not? If I want to say more clearly I want to make an android download manager and keep downloading in background according to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog). But after pause my android activity I lost the UI and that's while my service is running but I can't use it to update my UI through `ResultReviver`.

Comment: Sounds like you have a different problem then, because no matter whether or not it's an IntentService, you will need to re-attach to it. Neither Service nor IntentService do this by themselves. So you don't want to _resume_ it, you want to _re-attach_ to it.

Comment: @ClassStacker yup this is exactly what I want, How can I re-attach it?

Comment: Does it run in a different process as the Activity, in other words, do you use the `android:process` attribute in the manifest?

Comment: @ClassStacker I didn't using `android:process` attribute in the manifest.

Comment: @iSun I am a bit curious, if you send an Intent to an IntentService, then it will do what you ask for, then if you want to do it again you can send a new Intent. Does this not work for you?

Comment: I suggest that you use the search engine of your choice once more now that you have understood that you do not want to "resume" your IntentService.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) it is not possible.

> This is a subclass of Service that uses a worker thread to handle all
>   start requests, one at a time. This is the best option if you don't
>   require that your service handle multiple requests simultaneously. All
>   you need to do is implement onHandleIntent(), which receives the
>   intent for each start request so you can do the background work.

**For making download manger have the IntentService notify something (e.g., via a Messenger) about the failed download, so you can enqueue that file sometime later once Internet access returns**